# Photoset layout not working on tumblr

Tags: themes, tumblr

I am content with my current theme but the photosets are not laying out properly, they are the same width with my photos but say for instance i reblog a photoset with the photos side by side, it wont show up that way on my blog it will show up underneath each other and that is very frustrating since it makes the images blury.
This is my photoset html code. Is there anyway to correct this?

```
</div>
{/block:Photo}

{block:Photoset}
<div class="entry">
    <div class="photosetbox">

        {block:Photos}
<img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" class="highres">
{/block:Photos}

    {block:IndexPage}    
        <div class="photosett">
            {block:Date}
                {block:NoteCount}{NoteCountWithLabel}&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;{/block:NoteCount}<a href="{Permalink}">{12Hour}:{Minutes} {CapitalAmPm}</a>
            {/block:Date}
        </div>
            <div class="photoset_a">
                <a href="{ReblogURL}" target="_blank"></a>
            </div>
    {/block:IndexPage}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Photoset Photos**

Your current code specifies that you want each photo from photoset to rendered in the html as an `img` tag:

```
{block:Photos}
<img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" class="highres">
{/block:Photos}
```

To render a photoset, you have two options. Either use the built in feature / theme operator. This will give you an `iframe` with a photoset prebuilt inside it:

```
{Photoset-700}
```

Or use a plugin to take your current code and turn it into a photoset.

**References**

[Tumblr Theme Operators - Photosets](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#photoset-posts)

[Photoset Grid jQuery Plugin](https://github.com/stylehatch/photoset-grid)

Comment: Hello, thanks for this but when i replaced (photoUrl-HighRes) with (Photoset-700) it just made my blog really distorted

Comment: @user3705674 you replaced the code like for like? Can I see a link to the issue?

Comment: I replaced the code which didn't work so i found this code {block:IfLargePostsWidth}
            {Photoset-700}
        {/block:IfLargePostsWidth}                                               Which put the photosets side by side but cuts the right one off because it's too big, when i put {photoset-500} it is too small and doesnt match the width of my normal photos